# How to replace a character only in capturing group?

Tags: java, regex, notepad++

Suppose we have a list of strings

```
First Word Alfa
Second Word 
Third Word Gamma Saturn
```

etc

I want to write a regexp that will turn it into list of

```
new ColumnData(FIRST_WORD_ALFA, "First\n Word\n Alfa", String.class);
new ColumnData(SECOND_WORD, "Second\n Word", String.class);
new ColumnData(THIRD_WORD_GAMMA_SATURN, "Third\n Word\n Gamma\n Saturn", String.class);
```

Is there a way to replace a space symbol in capturing group?

More general question:
Suppose we have a text with some sentences in braces (). Is there a way to replace only spaces within those sentences with underlines?

Upd: The best I could come up with was replacing (.*) with 
new ColumnData(\U\1\E, "\1", String.class);
But I still need to replace spaces in two groups.

Upd2: Suppose I use Notepad++ for replacement. Or Java .replaceAll function

Comment: So what did you tried?

Comment: This would be heavily dependant on the tool/programming language you want to use? You should tag your question with this information.

Comment: This isn't possible in pure regex. You can either replace spaces with `\n ` _or_ enclose each line in `new ColumnData(..., String.class);`, but not both. And there's no way to produce the all-caps text (i.e. `FIRST_WORD_ALFA`) with just regex.

Comment: @Rawing it is possible to produce uppercase text with \U

Answer (score 1):

How about:

Find what: `^(\w+) (\w+) (\d+)`
Replace with: `new ColumnData\(\U$1_$2_$3\E, "$1\\n $2\\n $3", String.class\);`

Check `Regular expression` and click on <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: That will work for this case, but what if we have a variable number of words? How to replace smth in found results?

Comment: @Dia: Could you edit your question and add some sample cases with expected result?